# Null textfield with Tableview scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I have a problem to get the value of textfield when [which is in first section of tableview].
When im scrolling tableview i my textfield give me null result. How can i solve this problem. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me your tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Usually you get the value of a text field when you end editing, which you wouldn't be doing during a scroll. Can you explain what the user would be doing that you need to do this?

Comment: if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        LFMInsertarNombreYElegirCamisetaDeEquipoCell *cellB = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierB];
        [[cellB insertarNombreEquipo] setDelegate:self]; 
        [[cellB seleccionarEquipacion] addTarget:self action:@selector(seleccionarEquipacion) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 it is my cellforrowatindex . 
   
        

        return cellB;
    }
    else {
        if ( [[[listadoJugadoresSeleccionados objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]-1] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] codigo] ) {...

Comment: I have 2 different cells , one of them filled automicaly, other one , i need to fill textfield and save it. save button is below of tableview, When im scrolling tableview , i get nil result from textfield.text:(

Comment: Where you are using text field .. ?

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [listadoJugadoresPorTactica cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1];
    LFMSOAPValidarNuevoEquipoOperation *vNEquipo = [[LFMSOAPValidarNuevoEquipoOperation alloc] init];
    [vNEquipo setDelegate:self];
    [vNEquipo setJugadoesSeleccionados:listadoJugadoresSeleccionados];
    [vNEquipo setNombreEquipo:[textField text]];
    [vNEquipo setTactica:[self tactica]];
    [vNEquipo makeRequest];    This is the code to get text.

Comment: [[cellB insertarNombreEquipo] setDelegate:self]; // this is for my textfield that i have in cell.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a nil because tables reuse the cells so the information is not in the table, UITablesView are made to show information instead of saving it. You need to the strings in a independent NSArray and add them to each cell...

1) Instantiate all the NSStrings within numberOfRowsInSection, that way you'll know how many UITextFields you should.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

2) Use the UITextField delegate to replace the NSString in the Array as soon as its editing process ends

3) In cellForRow, set the text of the corresponding NSString using its position in the NSArray